# Save As to Variable File Paths

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to use an Excel-macro that will automatically save the workbook once certain cells are filled in. The macro will check when changes are made to specific cells, then use variable data to save the workbook through a folder system organized by year and quarter, while giving the Workbook a name based on the Current date and a cell number. The macro will also check to see if the network path (it being on a server) is connected, and if not, exit the sub. I am getting a compile error "Expected: end of statement" at

```
Set mTitle = Year(Now)," & . & ", Month(Now), " &.& ", Day(Now), " & - & ", ActiveWorkbooks.Sheets("Control").Cells(1, "C")
```

I want to save the workbook with the following format: `Year.Month.Day - CellValue`, but it looks like VBA doesn't like periods. How can I solve this? Full code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cYear As String
Dim Quarter As String
Dim fdObj As Object
Dim mTitle As String
Dim sCheck

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set cYear = Year(Now)
Set Quarter = (Month(Now) + 2) \ 3
Set fdObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sCheck = "S:\Estimating Data\Estimates\test.txt"
Set mTitle = Year(Now)," & . & ", Month(Now), " &.& ", Day(Now), " &.& ", ActiveWorkbooks.Sheets("Control").Cells(1, "C")

If Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C5")) Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
Else
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C1:C5")) = 0 Then
 Exit Sub
 Else

 Shell ("Net View \\S:\ > " & vsFileName)
    If FileLen(vsFileName) = 0 Then
    Exit Sub

Else

        If fdObj.FolderExists("S:\Estimating Data\Estimates\" & cYear & "\""Q" & Quarter & ".*xlsm") Then
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="S:\Estimating Data\Estimates\" & cYear & "\""Q" & Quarter & "\" & mTitle & ".*xlsm"
  Else
    fdObj.CreateFolder ("S:\Estimating Data\Estimates\" & cYear & "\""Q" & Quarter & ".*xlsm")

        End If

    End If

 End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `mTitle` is a *string type* variable so no need to use `Set`. You use [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-statement) in assigning objects to *object type* declared variables.

Comment: Adjusted mTitle per your suggestion, still getting the same error. It is highlighting the " &.& " part of the code.

Comment: Try this `mTitle = Format(Date,"yyyy.mm.dd") & " - " & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Cells(1, "C").Value`. I think you just missed the concatenation process. Also, it might be a typo but `ActiveWorkbooks` should be `ActiveWorkbook` (without ***s***).

Comment: That did it. Guess the ampersands go outside of the quotes then?

Comment: Yeah. It should. And when working with dates, you can use [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function instead of doing the concatenation by *Year,month,date*.

Comment: @L42's suggested line is better than what you were trying to write but, FWIW, what you were trying to write was probably `mTitle = Year(Now) & "." & Month(Now) & "." & Day(Now) & "." & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Control").Cells(1, "C").Value`